# Run a shell command automatically and directly after restarting and keep it running

Tags: linux, shell, command, startup

I have this shell command `asebamedulla "ser:device=/dev/ttyACM0"`, I want it to be run directly after restarting Linux.
I read some solutions ( `shell_command &` , or run in in background as a daemon process...) but I didn't know how to use them.
My question is :
**how to run a shell command automatically and directly after startup?**

Comment: Give a try to a supervisor: https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/

Comment: I just put it in .bashrc as follows : `command &` to make it run in background, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
>>sudo crontab -e

#In the first line of this file enter this:

@reboot <your command whatever>

#Save and Exit
```

Solution 2:

Make a script name it *"whatever.sh"*.

Put the file in your */etc/init.d/* directory.

Change the permission of your file by.

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/whatever.sh
```